# Event listener for increment button in input type="number"

Tags: javascript, html

[image]

In html, for input type="number", is there anyway to add an event listener to click the increase button. For example, if the user enters 0 then the increase button will be clicked 2 times. I know I can just change the value to 2 if the input is 0 but I just wonder whether we can do that using the increase button. Thanks

Comment: would `onchange` event listener suffice? This should fire-up whenever the value inside changes, so not only on the arrow-up, but also arrow-down, and direct input manipulation

Comment: can [step](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number#step) help you?

Comment: Track `change` or `input` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number
You can call `stepUp()` and/or `stepDown()`.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan you are correct, buddy!  I specifically said "you can call" - and meant: for any need, in addition to the tracking/event listening...

Comment: I solved this by checking the `inputType` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/InputEvent/inputType) property of the `input` event. If the increment or decrement button are clicked the `inputType` will be `insertReplacementText`, and it doesn't appear any other action results with this value of `inputType`. This sill leaves it to you to check whether the value was incremented or decremented.

Comment: Apparently `insertReplacementText` is only returned in Firefox, other browsers return `undefined`.